# I cannot create c++ projects in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-c++

I have recently upgraded from visual studio 2017 to vs 2019.

The problem is that I cannot create any c++ projects except for CUDA 10.1

When I choose all the project settings in vs and I click create, I get an error
**Object reference not set to an instance of the object.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Start Visual Studio, select "start without code", open "Manage extensions" and update them all. Try again.

Comment: Run the VS updater and see if c++ workflow is installed.